# can i set the url before returning the ModelAndView?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

is it possible to set your url before returning your model?

For example, my current url is http://localhost/home.html
at my homecontroller, I return a modelandview for another page, for example

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("contact");
model.addObject("contactNo", "12345");
return model;
```

then after returning the model, my contact.jsp has been loaded to my browser but it's url is still http://localhost/home.html, I want to change it to http://localhost/contact.html, 
how can i able to do that?

thanks

Comment: You may simply set view name with a redirect keyword: `modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/pageName"); return modelAndView;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try instantiating your `ModelAndView` like this,

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("contact"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The approved answer didn't work for me.

This did:

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("dashboard");
model.setViewName("redirect:dashboard.html");
```